# Using object values passed as a props from parent component

Tags: reactjs, object, react-props

I'm trying to use the values passed from my parent in my child component. I'm passing an object with I used a spread operator to do so

```
//Parent Component

 <Pagination {...pagination} />
```

I'm wondering how can I have access to the object values ? So far I found that I can console.log it with

```
//Child component

this.props.children.props.children.props.current
```

and get a correct value displayed but when I'm trying to store this value in a const and use it, it returns me undefined ? I'm pretty sure it's the way I'm trying to get the props value but I have no idea how... Thanks in advance !

Comment: in Pagination component just ```console.log(this.props)``` you get the idea

Answer (score 0):

All props passed to a component are accessible by accessing this.props.[propName].

If you destructure an object to a components props then all object properties are directly added to the components props. Example:

```
const x = { a: 1, b:2 };
<Component {...x} />
```

The values of "x" can now be accessed in "Component" through

```
this.props.a / this.props.b
```

Comment: Right now pagination is my object and it returns `current: 1
limit: 24
offset: 0
total: 365`. I tried to log this.props.current and it still returns undefined ?

Comment: @AlexandreSavard-Plante Have you logged pagination in render before you pass it as a prop and made sure that the values are not undefined at that time? If the values do exist and the problem still occurs please edit your post and add additional code to review.

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass a name so that child can use that name to access the object

//Parent component

```
 <Pagination pages = {...pagination} />
```

// Child Component

```
this.props.pages
```